# Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

How can I use these both OS on my laptop, without having to reinstall one? For my personal use I always had Ubuntu installed (13.10 32bit) as my single OS. Then for my new job I needed to install Win8.1 (64bit). Now I have these both OS on a separate partition, but I can boot only to a Win8.1 OS.

Is there a way that I can restore the Grub or whatever to do, in order to have a choice to boot any of my two OS (preferably without having to reinstall one)?

Comment: You most certainly can dual boot. The problem you are likely to have is that windows 8 requires uefi. You probably are going to need to enable uefi, install windows, and then try running boot-repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair You will need to boot a live usb with uefi enabled and run boot repair. If that fails you might be best off re-installing. At any rate, your question is a bit unclear as it is hard to know what if any problem you actually have encountered.

Comment: More  instructions for similar situation [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) - install windows first.